# Draw lines between buttons in a gridlayout in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have JPanel:

```
    JPanel GameBoardPanel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(yAxis,xAxis,30,30));
```

The panel holds x*y amount of buttons and now I'm trying draw lines in the "spacing" between them but I can't figure out how to do it. 
This picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDF06.png shows the gridpattern.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of buttons with heavy spacing in between them inside a single panel.  Put each button on a panel that has a custom border of a line and add each of these panels to your `GameBoardPanel`.  You will need to setup the individual panels with the buttons to have extra spacing where needed.

Unrelated, the standard Java naming convention for local variables is to start with a lower case character.

So change this:

```
JPanel GameBoardPanel
```

to:

```
JPanel gameBoardPanel
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to add these lines dynamically when I press a button so the buttons get connected.

Comment: If I understand correctly, if the board consists of 10x10 buttons, should I also create 100 panels and then put all of them in another JPanel with gridLayout to get the grid?

Comment: Same answer, just don't add the border until the button is pressed.

Comment: Yes, if it is 10 x 10 you would need 100 panels for your 100 buttons.

Comment: Do you have a link with good material regarding these custom borders?

Comment: The borders won't need to be custom. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html

Comment: I don't get it to work like I want it to. Is it possible to just draw a line on the panel?